# How to autoscroll a WebView HTML File?

Tags: java, android, html, autoscroll

I want to be able to autoscroll the page. Below is my method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");
  }
}
```

Edit: I don't want it to auto scrolled all the way to the bottom or top I want to autoscroll with speed so it goes to the bottom slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) enclosing your WebView in your main layout, and scroll it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks but that scrolls all the way to the bottom, I want to be able to autoscroll slowly with given speed.

Comment: I tried webview.scrollBy(x,y) but I am having another issue as posted in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467219/stop-when-webview-is-at-the-end